# Scala Pattern matching leading to two outputs

Tags: scala, split, match, case

I am matching a text file which has some columns [String Double Double Double Double]. I would like to obtain the following for each row of the file [String Double Double] and [String Double Double] wherein the String is the label same for both but I am splitting the first two doubles and last two doubles into two independent rows.

I am using the following which is not working:

```
val out = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.collect(_.split("\\s+").toList match {
      case s1 :: points1 :: points2 => (s1,"4",Point(points1.map(_.toDouble).toIndexedSeq))
                                    => (s1,"6",Point(points2.map(_.toDouble).toIndexedSeq))
```

My doubles are co-ordinates of points.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `points1` matches your second column and `points2` rest columns.
It's because in `::` notation left side is first element of list (head), but second is rest sublist (tail).

It may be easy to decompose row to list of all columns like this:

```
... match {
  case s1 :: p1x :: p1y :: p2x :: p2y :: Nil =>
```

Then you can compose it again to two rows, placing them in two-element list:

```
=> List( (s1,"4",Point(Vector(p1x,p1y).map(_.toDouble))),
         (s1,"6",Point(Vector(p2x,p2y).map(_.toDouble))) )
```

But then, in result you'll have a List[List[..]], so you need to flatten it. Simplest way is to use `flatMap` instead of `collect`.

So your full code will look like this:

```
val out = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\s+").toList match {
  case s1 :: p1x :: p1y :: p2x :: p2y :: Nil => 
    List( (s1,"4",Point(Vector(p1x,p1y).map(_.toDouble))),
          (s1,"6",Point(Vector(p2x,p2y).map(_.toDouble))) )
})
```